# Not all code paths return a value c#'

Tags: c#

I am attempting to use the following code and get the above error. I am definitely a novice coder so probably something simple. I am guessing it is something to do with if(a2dCollider). I need to check if the collider is present for this statement to work though.

```
     private bool CheckIndex(int cIndex, bool a2DCollider)
    {
        if (a2DCollider)
        {
            if (floatingObjects2D.Count <= cIndex)
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (floatingObjects2D[cIndex] == null)
            {
                floatingObjects2D.RemoveAt(cIndex);
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (floatingObjects3D.Count <= cIndex)
                return true;
            if (floatingObjects3D[cIndex] == null)
            {
                floatingObjects3D.RemoveAt(cIndex);
                return true;
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: What should it return if `a2DCollider` is `true` and `floatingObjects2D.Count > cIndex`?

Comment: Since you only ever return true, perhaps you meant to return false in all other cases?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the double `if`-statements in your `if-else` block.

If `a2DCollider` is `true` but the conditions of the two inner `if`-statements are `false, the function does not return anything.

Also, if `a2DCollider` is `false` but none of the two inner `if`-statements are `true`, the function does not return anything.

You could easily fix this by adding a `return false` line under the `if-else`, like this:

```
private bool CheckIndex(int cIndex, bool a2DCollider)
{
    if (a2DCollider)
    {
        if (floatingObjects2D.Count <= cIndex)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (floatingObjects2D[cIndex] == null)
        {
            floatingObjects2D.RemoveAt(cIndex);
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (floatingObjects3D.Count <= cIndex)
            return true;
        if (floatingObjects3D[cIndex] == null)
        {
            floatingObjects3D.RemoveAt(cIndex);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or make your function a `void` function since you just seem to return `true` everywhere and thus don't seem to use the return value for anything. Like this:

```
private void CheckIndex(int cIndex, bool a2DCollider)
{
    if (a2DCollider && floatingObjects2D[cIndex] == null)
    {
       floatingObjects2D.RemoveAt(cIndex);
    }          
    else if (floatingObjects3D[cIndex] == null)  
    {             
       floatingObjects3D.RemoveAt(cIndex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're make things too complicated, just return at the end of the code.

```
private bool CheckIndex(int cIndex, bool a2DCollider)
{
    if (a2DCollider && floatingObjects2D[cIndex] == null)
       floatingObjects2D.RemoveAt(cIndex);          
    else if (floatingObjects3D[cIndex] == null)               
       floatingObjects3D.RemoveAt(cIndex)            
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not cover all the possible scenarios for the parameters you give to the function while running in the `if - else` statements. You need to tell the program what to do if this conditions are not met, by using the `else`:

```
private bool CheckIndex(int cIndex, bool a2DCollider)
    {
        if (a2DCollider)
        {
            if (floatingObjects2D.Count <= cIndex)
                return true;
            if (floatingObjects2D[cIndex] == null)
            {
                floatingObjects2D.RemoveAt(cIndex);
                return true;
            }
            else
                // return something
        }
        else
        {
            if (floatingObjects3D.Count <= cIndex)
                return true;
            if (floatingObjects3D[cIndex] == null)
            {
                floatingObjects3D.RemoveAt(cIndex);
                return true;
            }
            else
                // return something
        }
    }
```

Alternatively, you can return `false` or `true` as default if no other value was returned before, by declaring it in the end of the function, that will make sure your function will provide output (and return value) always:

```
private bool CheckIndex(int cIndex, bool a2DCollider)
{
    if (a2DCollider)
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Yup :o), Someone told me just to put return false at the end on the Unity forums and it worked perfectly. Thank you for all the quick answers everyone.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if 'floatingObjects2D[cIndex] != null'? You need an else